# Server Wait Time Shoots up to 5-6 seconds

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm, nameservers

[image]

As you can see, the wait time for this website http://quotepix.com and all other websites on the server have shot up to 5-10seconds.

This time sometimes reduces back to less than 0.5s at times, but the same issue pops up after a few hours. This has been happening for the past 3-5 days

Strange part is, if i try logging into cpanel/WHM, all the requests go really fast. Meaning the same domain, just loads instantly instead of the 5s wait time where it shows connecting... connecting in the browser

Another thing is, its only the first request in a tab in the browser that takes so long to load. After the initial HTML load, all other urls and subsequent links on the page load instantly.

I've googled a lot and tried random fixes. Removed the Apache reverse lookup, removed it from logging also. No permanent fix yet